# Azure AD SSO in a DMZ server

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I have implemented Azure AD SSO for a ASP.net Web application. Everything works fine in Dev and QA servers. The issue is when I move this application to Production; login is not working. The Production server is in a DMZ space which has restrictions to connect to the internet. I was told that I needed to open up ports to particular urls in order to connect Azure from the DMZ server. But, as per our networking team, the firewall rule cannot allow FQDN like "login.microsoftonline.com", we need to get IPs instead. But, as far as I know,  Microsoft is not providing the IPs as these IPs may change time to time. What are my options here? Thanks for the suggestions.

Best,
Jaleel

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to make use of a web proxy to connect to the Azure AD related urls. And then the application needs a configuration change to utilize this proxy like this and now it works  fine

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://yourproxyserver:yourproxyport" bypassonlocal="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```